# How can I make a n order Hamilton-connected graph by using no more than (3n+1)/2 edges

Tags: graph-theory

There is a theorem as "if G is a Hamilton-connected graph and $|V(G)|⩾4$, the following inequation holds: $|E(G)|⩾[\frac{3|V(G)|+1}{2}]$".But can the minimun bound can be got?

this is one of problems from my homework and I can't solve it.

Comment: Do you know standard example of Hamilton-connected graphs ? Which ones have you tried?

Comment: For n=4,5，it is easy to make such graph .but with the vertices adding more and more,I can't find a common solution to stucture such graphs.And I don't know about standard example of Hamilton-connected graphs

Comment: Have a look at the examples at the bottom of the page. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hamilton-ConnectedGraph.html